# How do I return pixel coordinate values from the following function?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I already have an extensive script that's functioning well. The purpose of the script is to iterate over images and draw rectangles around a specific species within the imagery, based upon previously manually extracted pixel coordinate data.

Now however, I wish to return/extract the pixel coordinate values of each of the four corners of the rectangle, as calculated and drawn in the 'draw.rectangle' line of the 'for loop' below:

```
for index, row in img1_df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(img1_df)):
        draw.rectangle(((float(row['x'])-float(row['r']), float(row['y'])-float(row['r'])), (float(row['x'])+float(row['r']), float(row['y'])+float(row['r']))), fill=(255,0,0,55))
```

I would preferably like this in .csv format, with 5 columns arranged as (or something similar to): 'filename', top left (x/y), bottom left (x/y), top right (x/y), bottom right (x/y).

How do I achieve this?

Thanks, R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). You want to use a `csv.writer` instance and use it to write your data into a file. Something like this should work:

```
import csv

with open('coordinates.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for index, row in img1_df.iterrows():
        for i in range(len(img1_df)):
            writer.writerow([(float(row['x'])-float(row['r']), float(row['y'])- float(row['r'])),
                             (float(row['x'])+float(row['r']), float(row['y'])+float(row['r']))])
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I replied to this comment @MilanCermak ! Thank you, this was very helpful, and with a few tweeks I managed to get this working well as part of my entire script. This now gives me a .csv file with four pixel coordinate values, two for the x/y coordinates of the top left corner, and two for the x/y coordinates of the bottom right corner. How could I modify this to return the x/y coords of the centerpoint, as well as the height and width? Thanks again. R

Comment: If you have the x/y for top-left and bottom-right corners, finding the height, width and center is just simple arithmetic, isn't it? Calculate that and add it to the list in the writerow function.

Comment: Yes your right, sorry I was kind of thinking aloud when I wrote that.... I have now made the necessary changes, and my 'writer.writerow' function is now as follows: `writer.writerow([(float(row['x']),float(row['y'])), float(row['y'])+float(row['y']), float(row['x'])+float(row['x'])])` . However, I'd also like to include the 'filename' in the .csv file, byt whenever i try to add this as a column the script wont execute. How do I implement this? Thanks again @MilanCermak

Comment: Add a new value to the list you pass to writerow?

Comment: I tried `writer.writerow([(float(row['filename'])), (float(row['x']),float(row['y'])), (float(row['r'])+float(row['r'])), (float(row['r'])+float(row['r']))])` but that didnt work.

Comment: Don't worry, I have worked it out! Thank you so much for your help man!